What reference is Deadpool making in his line, "What is it, girl? Is there trouble at the well?"
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), there's a scene where Sabretooth suddenly stops moving and reacts in pain in front of Deadpool after being struck down by Wolverine. Deadpool, in his typical snarky fashion, then says to Sabretooth:

What is it, girl? Is there trouble at the well?

Given Deadpool's penchant for pop culture references, this line is likely a nod to something specific. Does anyone know what work he might be referencing here? I have a feeling it could be from a movie, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

I do hope that for the UK showings, someone has the presence of mind to replace this with "trouble at the mill", because nobody expects the Spanish inquisition.

@EikePierstorff "t'mill", you mean.

Well, now I feel officially old.   Get offa my lawn, anyone who doesnt remember B&W TV sets.

@CarlWitthoft In case you don't feel old enough: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25315/how-did-people-get-apps-on-their-computer-before-the-internet

@Clockwork   ouch!    At least I never had to borrow anyone's stack of Hollerith cards!

@CarlWitthoft I learnt to program by hand-punching Hollerith cards!

As well as the more specific Lassie reference (since there's a dog at hand), t's a common "Western" or "Cowboy" reference.  Perhaps you remember one of the most famous lines in Toy Story, which is Woody's hilariously bad recorded voice "Somebody's poisoned the waterhole ..."  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6THteoyEWHo .. same idea.

It's probably a reference to Lassie.
In the movies, Lassie would bark and the people would ask questions that tell the viewer what the dog is trying to "say."
It was sort of a pop culture joke to expand a single bark to a long paragraph.
The boy that Lassie belonged to was always getting into problems - like getting trapped in an old mine or falling down an old well.
That led to things like:

Lassie:  Bark!
Boy's dad:
What?  Bobby's fallen down a well in the back 40 of the old McGruder farm and broken his leg?
Lassie:
Bark, bark!
Boy's dad:
Right! We'll go get the doctor and some folks to help dig and ropes to pull Bobby out.

From the description of the scene, Sabretooth grunted or something, then Deadpool snarked about the well.  That's got to be a Lassie reference.

this answer is right on target! my wife's family had a running gag based on this. Whenever someone would say something unintelligible someone else would respond with 'What's that? Timmy is stuck in the well?'

No argument that the line is always something like, "What's that boy?  Timmy fell down a well?"  It's fun to note that like so many of these things, Timmy never fell down a well on Lassie.

yeah, timmy is the name i believe

@JasonPatterson I'm pretty sure that the line would always be something like “What's that girl?”.  It would be unusual to name a male dog “Lassie”.

@MarkDominus Famously, while Lassie, the character, was female, every dog that played her was male.

To add to the connection/confusion, Lassie herself fell down a well in "Lassie: Well of Love." This TV movie appears to have been made near the end of the Lassie series, so the writers may have been indirectly acknowledging the trope even then by reversing the danger. Or maybe they just really liked wells.

Btw, there was an earlier incarnation of "Lassie", in which the kid was "Jeff", and the grown-ups were his mom and "Gramps". No dad. Gramps referred to the "rahdio" as a new-fangled gadget. This must have been in the middle-1950s. :)

To expand on the Lassie thing, it's a common trope that is well referenced (pun intended, because... Deadpool)

A Stock Plot in which Little Billy falls into danger and the family pet or another animal (usually domesticated) takes the initiative to either rescue Billy or (more commonly) summon an adult character to help him. Parodied to the point of being a Discredited Trope by now, maybe even a Dead Horse Trope. Still, expect a riff on "What is it, girl? Is Timmy in the well?" when one character isn't sure what another character is trying to tell them.

In Deadpool's case, he's doing his backhanded joke at Sabretooth's expense, by treating him like a literal dog.
In one of life's greatest ironies, the famous Lassie show that inspired the trope never featured a boy falling down a well.

The series initially depicted Lassie as the pet of farm boy Jeff Miller (Tommy Rettig), and in later seasons Timmy Martin (Jon Provost), of "What's that, Lassie? Timmy's fallen down a well?" fame — although a well was actually one of the few things Timmy didn't fall down in the course of the series. Lassie knocks a corrupt water executive down a well during the Jeff seasons!


It's actually likely a mix of the 2 tropes referenced in other answers. The dialogue chosen doesn't really make sense with one alone.

The mythical "What's that girl, X has fallen down the well?" from Lassie (which never happened in the series, it was a contemporary poke at the absurdity of the adventures).

and

The Northern English humorous reference to shenanigans happening in (normally) a shared social hinterland, "trouble at t'mill". While this is a well-known phrase in the UK, it will likely have passed into American (especially comedy writers) parlance through the famous Spanish Inquisition sketch by Monty Python.

Supporting links as requested (some duplicated from other answers)
Phrase history:
https://wordhistories.net/2020/05/15/trouble-at-tmill/
Monty Python reference:
https://www.ibras.dk/montypython/episode15.htm
Clever Lassie:
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimmyInAWell
